# Google chart shrinks when switching bootstrap tabs html

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

I am using google charts in containers and have two tabs each having two charts. When i switch to between tabs the chart size shrinks and when only any filter is applied it comes to normal size.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script>
        google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart','treemap','controls', 'table', 'gauge']});

        function changeGraph(chartOption1,chartOption2,chartOption3) {
            var value1 =<?php echo $dataSet1;  ?>;
            var value3 =<?php echo $dataSet3;  ?>;
            var value4 =<?php echo $dataSet4;  ?>;

            jsonTest(value1);
            jsonTest2(value1,chartOption1);
            jsonTest3(value3,chartOption2);
            pieChart(value4,chartOption3);
        }

        function chartType(param1,param2,param3) {
            var refreshElements = document.getElementsByClassName("innercharts")
            for(i=0;i<refreshElements.length;i++)
            {
                var refreshElement = refreshElements[i]
                refreshElement.innerHTML = ""
            }
            var element1 = document.getElementById("url1");
            var element2 = document.getElementById("url2");
            var element3 = document.getElementById("url3");
            element1.value = param1;
            element2.value = param2;
            element3.value = param3;
            changeGraph(element1.value,element2.value,element3.value);
        }

        function tabFunc(evt, evtName) {
            // Declare all variables
            var i, tabcontent, tablinks;


            tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
            for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
                tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
            }

            // Get all elements with class="tablinks" and remove the class "active"
            tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
            for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
                tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
            }
            
            // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the button that opened the tab
            document.getElementById(evtName).style.display = "block";
            evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
            console.log(evt.currentTarget.className);
        }
        function start(){
            changeGraph('is_ethnic_descent','category_group','net_payment_amount');
        }

    </script>
</head>

<!--<body>-->
<body onload="start()">

<div class="tab">
    <button id="defaultopen" class="tablinks active" onclick="tabFunc(event, 'Membership')">Membership</button>
    <button class="tablinks" onclick="tabFunc(event, 'Revenue')">Revenue</button>
</div>

<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="Membership" class="tabcontent">
    </br>
    <h2>User counts per gender and season</h2>
    <div id="container1" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">

        <table class="columns" style="width:50%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="filter_div"></div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div id="slider_div"></div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class = "innercharts" id="container"></div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <h2>Counts per start date of program</h2>
    <div id="container5" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">

        <table class="columns" style="width:75%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="filter_div2"></div>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <div id="slider_div2"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select style="min-height:40px;min-width:100px;" id = "onchangeid1" onchange="chartType(this.value,onchangeid2.value,onchangeid3.value)">
                        <!--                        <option value="Choose" selected="selected">Select report</option>-->
                        <option value="category_group" selected="selected">Category Group</option>
                        <option value="category" >Category</option>
                        <option value="is_ethnic_descent" >Ethnic minority</option>
                    </select>
                    <a id="url1"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div id="filter_div3"></div>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div id="container2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="Revenue" class="tabcontent">
    </br>
    <h2>Registration revenue per year</h2>
    <div id="container3" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">
        <table class="columns" style="width:70%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="filter_div4"></div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select style="min-height:40px;min-width:100px;" id = "onchangeid2" onchange="chartType(onchangeid2.value,this.value, onchangeid3.value)">
                        <!--                        <option value="Choose" selected="selected">Select report</option>-->
                        <option value="category_group" selected="selected">Category Group</option>
                        <option value="category" >Category</option>
                        <option value="club" >Club</option>
                    </select>
                    <a id="url2"></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <div id="filter_div5"></div>
            </tr>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <div class = "innercharts" id="container4"></div>
    </div>
    </br>
    <h2>Events revenue per year</h2>
    <div id="container6" style="border:1px solid #cecece;">
        <div id = "container4">
            <table class="columns" style="width:70%">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select style="min-height:40px;min-width:100px;" id = "onchangeid3" onchange="chartType(onchangeid1.value,onchangeid2.value,this.value)">
                            <option value="net_payment_amount" selected="selected">Net pay</option>
                            <option value="payment_amount_gross" >Gross pay</option>
                            <option value="refund_amount" >Refunds</option>
                            <option value="service_fees" >Service fees</option>
                        </select>
                        <a id="url3"></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<script>

    document.getElementById("defaultopen").click();

</script>

</body>
```

I know there is an issue where with bootstrap css that shriks the content in next tab. How could a fix/hack be done here?